# How is Deadly Strike calculated?

Tags: diablo-ii

When I was playing on my Zealadin, a friend of mine gave me a sword that had the Deadly Strike bonus applied to it.

I'm not entirely sure this sword was legit (it could have very well been a modded weapon, but I don't even know how to tell). The thing that interested me was that, by the time I hit level 99, the Deadly Strike bonus was up to +600% Chance of Deadly Strike.

**What does this bonus signify? Or, more importantly, how is its bonus damage calculated?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information on Deadly Strike is scare, but basically, it's the same as Critical Strike which allows for a multiplier on damage dealt. This is what I found from [Diablo Wiki](http://www.diablowiki.com/Deadly_Strike_%28Diablo_II%29) and [ExtremeGamerz](http://extreme-gamerz.org/diablo2/viewdiablo2/woundsstrikesblows)

Some things to note about Deadly Strike:

- All melee damage is doubled, whether its physical, magic or elemental
- Deadly strike is the last thing that's applied to your damage, so the existing modifiers are taken into account
- Deadly Strike & Critical Strike are mutually exclusive, so both cannot stack up & be applied at the same time:
- Chance to do double damage is given by: Real chance to do double damage = Critical Strike + (Deadly Strike / 100) * (100 - Critical Strike)
- There is no cap on how high the chance to trigger a deadly strike can get, but anything over 100% is pointless because it can be active only once per attack.

Comment: So, it would technically hit 5 times using Zeal, correct?

Comment: given that each strike using Zeal acts as a self contained attack, I'd say yes. @Fluttershy

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if each hit within Zeal counted as its own attack.